# Implement prototype-similar functionality for WinForms controls hosted in IE

Tags: javascript, winforms, internet-explorer, com

I'm using `WinForms` controls in IE. Something similar to this:

```
var MyControl = new ActiveXObject("MyComponent.MyControl")
```

And I want to be able to use prototype feature for MyControl:

```
MyControl.prototype.newFunc = function(){
    alert('hi there');
}
```

Is it possible at all? I thought about `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Expando`, but I can't find any comprehensive documentation about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any way to modify the prototype of an ActiveX object because they do not inherit from the native js Object and therefore do not have a prototype.

Comment: Okay, and what if I use IExpando interface? Will I be able to add arbitrary fields to my ActiveX object in javascript code?